# Compute the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-k}^k \frac{\sin(x^k)}{x^{k-2}} \ dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Compute the limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{-k}^k \frac{\sin(x^k)}{x^{k-2}} \ dx.$$

Is the monotone convergence theorem or dominated convergence theorem useful here? If I denote $f_k(x)= \frac{\sin(x^k)}{x^{k-2}} \le \frac{1}{x^{k-2}}$, but I cannot get any bounding function $g(x)$ for this since I don’t know how to approximate this term $\frac{1}{x^{k-2}}$ further. What options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {\sin (x^{k})} {x^{k-2}} dx- \int_{-1}^{1} x^{2}dx= \int_{-1}^{1} x^{2}\left(1-\frac {\sin (x^{k})} {x^{k}}\right)dx \to 0,$$  since $\left|1-\dfrac {\sin t} t \right|$ is bounded and tends to $1$ as $t \to 0$. Hence $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac {\sin (x^{k})} {x^{k-2}}dx \to \frac 2  3$.

$$\int_{|x|>1}\frac {\sin (x^{k})} {x^{k-2}} dx \to 0.$$ For this use DCT: $|\sin t| \leq 1$ and $\dfrac 1 {x^{k-2}} \leq \dfrac 1 {x^{2}}$ for $k \geq 4$.